# Unable to resolve sync conflict when using Azure Mobile Client - error keeps coming back

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm using a Node.JS backend on Azure with Easy Tables. The table contains the required columns to support offline syncing.
While testing the sync process I noticed that conflicts keep coming back even though I'm resolving them.

My test:

- Pull table content from Azure to iOS and Android device
- Change a record on iOS but don't sync back to Azure
- Change the same record on Android and sync
- Now sync iOS

As expected, the conflict is detected correctly and I catch a `MobileServicePushFailedException`. I am then resolving the error by replacing the local item with the server item:

```
localItem.AzureVersion = serverItem.AzureVersion;
await result.UpdateOperationAsync(JObject.FromObject (localItem));
```

However, the next time I sync, the same item fails again with the same error.

The `AzureVersion` property is declared like this:

```
[Version]
public string AzureVersion { get; set; }
```

What exactly is `result.UpdateOperationAsync()` doing? Does it update my local database? Do I have to do it manually? 
And also: am I supposed to trigger an explicit `PushAsync()` afterwards?

**EDIT:**
I changed the property from `AzureVersion` to `Version` and it works. I noticed that the `serverItem`'s `AzureVersion` property was NULL even though the JSON contained it. Bug in Json.Net or in the Azure Mobile Client?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using something like the following:

```
public async Task SyncAsync()
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;

    try
    {
        await this.client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

        await this.todoTable.PullAsync(
            //The first parameter is a query name that is used internally by the client SDK to implement incremental sync.
            //Use a different query name for each unique query in your program
            "allTodoItems",
            this.todoTable.CreateQuery());
    }
    catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
    {
        if (exc.PushResult != null)
        {
            syncErrors = exc.PushResult.Errors;
        }
    }

    // Simple error/conflict handling. A real application would handle the various errors like network conditions,
    // server conflicts and others via the IMobileServiceSyncHandler.
    if (syncErrors != null)
    {
        foreach (var error in syncErrors)
        {
            if (error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Update && error.Result != null)
            {
                //Update failed, reverting to server's copy.
                await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(error.Result);
            }
            else
            {
                // Discard local change.
                await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(@"Error executing sync operation. Item: {0} ({1}). Operation discarded.", error.TableName, error.Item["id"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `CancelAndUpdateItemAsync()`, which updates the item to the server copy or `CancelAndDiscardItemAsync()`, which accepts the local item.  These are the important things for you.

This code came from the official HOWTO docs here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/##offlinesync